# How do I modify the Previous and Next Page posts on blog pages to include "previous" and "next" before the links?

Tags: php, templates, next-post-link, previous-post-link

I want to add "previous" and"next" to the individual blogs since they only have the blog titles for the next and previous links. I want to keep the links and I am having a hard time using any of the solutions provided to me and they seem to make the page worse. Am I coding the information incorrectly or am I deleting important PHP that needs to stay?

This is the problem I am dealing with:

```
wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . esc_html__( 'Pages:', 'thermal-tech' ),
            'after'  => '</div>', ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this very easily using `the_post_navigation`. The [WordPress reference page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_navigation/) for it has more information.

```
the_post_navigation( array(
                'prev_text'=>__('Previous: %title'),
                'next_text'=>__('Next: %title'),
            ));
```

That said, if you do want to continue using `wp_link_pages' then, again, its [WordPress resource](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_link_pages/) is your friend, explaining the parameters and how to change them.

Hope that helps!